# Use Sed to Update Text in Bourne Shell

Tags: sed, sh

I'm trying to update a file in Bourne Shell. The user inputs a name and then is prompted to change the persons name, age and courses. Here's part of the code I've written:

```
  echo "please enter the name: \c"
   read updateInput

   updateNumber=$(grep -cwi "$updateInput" database.txt)
   updateRecord=$(grep -i "$updateInput" database.txt)

   test=$(! grep -i "$updateInput" database.txt)

   if [ "$updateNumber" -gt "1" ]
   then
          echo "ambiguous input"
   elif [ "$updateRecord" = "" ]
   then
           echo "record not found"
   else
           lineNumber=$(grep -ni $updateInput database.txt | cut -f1 -d:)

           grep -i $updateInput database.txt > tmp
           read first last age course1 course2 < tmp

           echo "record found, enter new value now:"
           echo "name ($first $last): \c" 
           read uFirst uLast
           if [ "$uFirst" != "" ]
           then
                   sed "$lineNumber s/$first/$uFirst/" database.txt
           fi
           if [ "$uLast" != "" ]
           then
                   sed "$lineNumber s/$last/$uLast/g" database.txt
           fi
```

When run, sed outputs the correct output with the right things changed, but it doesn't actually update the database file at all. I've tried googling all sorts of things, but nothing is working. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome. Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2):

If this is GNU `sed`, you can use the `-i` option to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i "$lineNumber s/$first/$uFirst/" database.txt
```

Otherwise, you will need to capture the sed output into a temporary file, then copy it over the original file.

Comment: When I use -i I get this error: "sed: 1: "database.txt": extra characters at the end of d command" @danza

Comment: DON'T do experiments on the actual text file! :) i think it's taking `database.txt` as a command. do some experiment with sed from command line on another file, and then go back to your script